# Scalable way to listen dynamically added contracts in web3j

Tags: events, web3j, logs

Consider I need to listen to the event logs for a Uniswap's `Swap` method, which works perfect for a single CA, or even to many if they are known to the time of creation of filter:

```
web3j.ethLogFlowable(makeFilter(listOf(lpAddress1, lpAddress2, ...)))
        .filter {...}.subscribe {...}

fun makeFilter(
    contractAddresses: List<String>,
    firstBlock: DefaultBlockParameter = DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST,
    lastBlock: DefaultBlockParameter = DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST
) = EthFilter(firstBlock, lastBlock, contractAddresses)
```

Meanwhile, I don't know how to effectively add a new contract to the existing subscription – should I recreate a filter and rebuild a subscription completely, or is there a way to **dynamically** add a new contract to the list of listened? Number of contracts could be hundreds or even thousands.

TL;TD; Is there is a way to modify list of filtered CAs in eth logs subs?